# Can't open phpMyAdmin (Windows)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I downloaded XAMPP three days ago and I keep getting this error when trying to open phpmyadmin.

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I haven't even set a password because I can't open the security page, I keep getting a *page not found* error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: are you sure that the database server is also started? The XAMP admin panel should tell you this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, trying to connect MySQL via command line to verify if MySQL server is running and user password is correct

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD
```

If you can successfully connect to the server go to phpmyadmin configure file
and change your connection string configuration.

See this: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html

But if you cannot connect to the MySQL server, your problem is your server not phpmyadmin. So go to your xampp control panel and configure the server configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked the MySQL server to be up and running, then check out the phpmyadmin config.sample.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin folder inside xampp.

Once there, check if the last line (AllowNoPassword) in this block

`/* Authentication type */`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

`/* Server parameters */`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`

is set to "false". If it is, flip it to true and that should help fix the issue